# Print delim used by strtok_r

Tags: c, strtok

I have this text for example:

```
I know,, more.- today, than yesterday!
```

And I'm extracting words with this code:

```
while(getline(&line, &len, fpSourceFile) > 0) {
  last_word = NULL;
  word = strtok_r(line, delim, &last_word);

  while(word){
    printf("%s ", word);
    word = strtok_r(NULL, delim, &last_word);
    // delim_used = ;
  }
}
```

The output is:

```
I know more today than yesterday
```

But there is any way to get the delimiter used by `strtok_r()`? I want to replace same words by one integer, and do the same with delimiters. I can get one word with `strtok_r()`, but how get the delimiter used by that function?

Comment: There is no way to know after use because actually used delimiter is replaced by 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, `strtok_r()` is a pretty simple function - it's easy to create your own variant that does what you need:

```
#include <string.h>

/* 
 * public domain strtok_ex() based on a public domain 
 *      strtok_r() by Charlie Gordon
 *
 *   strtok_r from comp.lang.c  9/14/2007
 *
 *      http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c/msg/2ab1ecbb86646684
 *
 *     (Declaration that it's public domain):
 *      http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c/msg/7c7b39328fefab9c
 */

 /*
    strtok_ex() is an extended version of strtok_r() that optinally 
    returns the delimited that was used to terminate the token

    the first 3 parameters are the same as for strtok_r(), the last
    parameter:

        char* delim_found

    is an optional pointer to a character that will get the value of
    the delimiter that was found to terminate the token.

 */
char* strtok_ex(
    char *str, 
    const char *delim, 
    char **nextp,
    char* delim_found)
{
    char *ret;
    char tmp;

    if (!delim_found) delim_found = &tmp;

    if (str == NULL)
    {
        str = *nextp;
    }

    str += strspn(str, delim);

    if (*str == '\0')
    {
        *delim_found = '\0';
        return NULL;
    }

    ret = str;

    str += strcspn(str, delim);

    *delim_found = *str;
    if (*str)
    {
        *str++ = '\0';
    }

    *nextp = str;

    return ret;
}


#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char delim[] = " ,.-!";
    char line[] = "I know,, more.- today, than yesterday!";

    char delim_used;    
    char* last_word = NULL;
    char* word = strtok_ex(line, delim, &last_word, &delim_used);

    while (word) {
        printf("word: \"%s\" \tdelim: \'%c\'\n", word, delim_used);
        word = strtok_ex(NULL, delim, &last_word, &delim_used);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Getting any skipped delimiters would be a bit more work. I don't think it would be a lot of work, but I do think the interface would be unwieldy (`strtok_ex()`'s interface is already clunky), so you'd have to put some thought into that.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot identify the delimiter (by means of the call to `strtok_r()` itself).

From [`man strtok_r`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html):

> **BUGS**
>
> [...]
>
> - The identity of the delimiting byte is lost.